# ggplot won't apply alpha value to some data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Absolute beginner on ggplot. I am plotting the `iris` dataset and when I set `alpha=0.5`, it won't apply to some data points.
Here is the code:

```
ggplot(iris)+
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,colour=Species),size=5,alpha=0.5)+
  labs(x="Sepal Length",y="Sepal Width")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Here is the output I got. As can be seen, the alpha value is not consistent throughout the data points.
[image]

Comment: That's not the correct interpretation. Those dots are darker precisely because of `alpha` and the fact that some points *are repeated in the data* (and therefore there are multiple translucent dots in those locations). See `table(with(iris, table(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)))`, showing that 90 times the width/length pair is unique, 22 times there are two such pairs, 4 times there are three rows with the same pair, and 1 time there are four such rows.

Comment: Slightly more verbose is `with(iris, table(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length))` showing pairs (column/row combos) and how many times each occurs (values in the table).

Comment: So you mean the color got darker because of same points stacking on top of each other?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: @MoonChild that's the point of transparency. If you want a uniform lighter color, you keep full opacity and pick a lighter color. The benefit of transparency is that you can see a bit of what's underneath.

Comment: @GregorThomas I agree. A nice feature, also a negative point of using geom_points. It was very well documented on help. Should've looked at it first. But nvm, maybe someone will find it useful ?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a negative of using `geom_point`. There are plenty of cases where what you want *is* to use opacity to show that multiple observations have the same coordinates. It's a matter of being intentional with what you're plotting, how, and why. Like if you don't want to see overlapping points based on opacity, don't set alpha below 1.

Comment: @camille I agree that it might be useful in some situations. I said a negative point based on what was mentioned in the docs: `The biggest potential problem with a scatterplot is overplotting: whenever you have more than a few points, points may be plotted on top of one another. This can severely distort the visual appearance of the plot.`

Comment: Also, just a query, how does it behave if different species have the same data point? Will it mix the colors?

Comment: Sure, try it and see what happens. It's mostly your blue & green points that overlap, and some do appear kind of teal, but you can change the colors to see more clearly where they mix, e.g. make one of those groups yellow instead

Answer (score 1):

The alpha value is being applied, but what you are seeing is due to some points overlapping others exactly. You can see this if you select geom_jitter instead of geom_point:

```
ggplot(iris)+
  geom_jitter(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,colour=Species),size=5,alpha=0.5)+
  labs(x="Sepal Length",y="Sepal Width")+
  theme_minimal()
```

When you set alpha to .5, it means that if there are 2 overlapping points, then you will get full color (2 * 0.5 = 1). If you wish to have points remain transparent even when there is overlap, then you can simply select a lower alpha value. The fact that it gets darker with overlap is a nice property, because it means that you can see where there might be large clusters of points.